# site.css is not working for my sample web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Newbie here.

I have created an empty MVC project in VS2010 and I'm trying to format my view for authentication. So, I've added this to site.css:

```
.rez 
{
color: Olive;
}
```

and this to my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
<label class="rez">Username</label><input type="text" name="Username"/>
</div>
<div>
Password<input type="password" name="Password"/>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="Log"/>
</div>
}
```

It's not working. I haven't touched routing or bundleconfig. I've configured web.config for authentication. _ViewStart and _Layout are also unchanged.

What am I doing wrong and more importantly how do I debug this issue. I'm using chrome.

Comment: Are you sure Site.css is loaded? If not run your project in IE and press F12, go to the Network tab and click on the 'Start Capturing' button, refresh your page and make sure you do not get any 404 errors.

Comment: please confirm  you add _layout to your cshtml page.

Comment: inspect it and see what css style is put on label tag

Comment: _layout is used while rendering my view.

Comment: I think that Site.css is not loaded. Chrome for my label element says this under Matched CSS Rules: label {
cursor: default;
}

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and I found out that the name of the file is "*Site.css*" and the file which is getting referenced in the *BundleConfig.cs* is "*site.css*" with lowercase *s*. I simply matched the file names and it worked.

edit: another thing to try is open inspect element of your browser, right click on the refresh button and hit empty cache and hard reload.

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed my problem. In BundleConfig I have changed the case :["~/Content/site.css" to "~/Content/Site.css"]

Comment: "hard reload"! Unbelievable ... but it works. Restart VS, no. Browser hard reload, yes.

Comment: Clear cache fixed my problem

Answer (score 4):

If you have added the CSS file to your content directory folder ensure that you are calling `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`

Comment: This line is in _Layout.cshtml by default. Haven't changed it.

Comment: I had the same issue, I don't remember changing it, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Naming Difference Found in Asp.net MVC 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnVCi.png)

**case sensitive**

**the problem is due to the file we're accessing, defined in ~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs and the file we're applying changes in ~/Content/Site.css**

In BundleConfig.cs we have:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

but in project directory we have:

```
~/Content/Site.css
```

Solution : Make sure to have the same file names.

Answer (score 0):

My site was working fine. I updated the nuget packages and none of the styles would work. Rolling back bootstrap to a previous version fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My site was working fine before being deployed after deployment the site.css was not being loaded, I found out by removing ~ from the ref worked for me from "~/css/site.css" to this "/css/site.css" and works fine now, you can also verify if the ref is within the "<"environment exclude="Development"">" tag.