# CSS class not overriding bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a default MVC project created in VS2017. So I have default Bootstrap.css and my Site.css files.

in the _Layout.cshtml file I have inserted an image

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img class="jamClass" src="~/Content/Images/Gravit_Bridge_Sync.svg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The image is showing fine but I'm trying to implement a size change using my `Site.css` file, i.e. with `jamClass` - instead of writing the size change in-line.

In my `site.css` I've tried increasing the "priority points" as seems to be the answer for many questions like this, but I just can't get any change to register.

I've tried:

```
a.jamClass{width:50px}
#.jamClass{width:50px}
.jamClass{wdith:50px}
```

I think I might be going about this the wrong way. I'm not even sure the Site.css is having any affect at all but I don't want to be changing the bootstrap.css files?

It's frustrating because it's so easy to do inline but I'm trying to do it the "proper" way!

---

**EDIT and ANSWER**
**WOW** the real reason this wasn't working was because my `Site.css` created by default was not referenced properly in the `BundleConfig` file - it was lower-case `s`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400087/site-css-is-not-working-for-my-sample-web-site) for where I found the suggestion.

Comment: give !important to your css code

Comment: you should be calling class by using .(period) not `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `.jamClass` on image, then the style should be like,

`img.jamClass { width: 50px; }` if this is not work try to use more parent class to prior high.

`.navbar-header img.jamClass { width: 50px; }` or

`.navbar .navbar-header img.jamClass { width: 50px; }`

NOTE: You should try to not use `!important`

Comment: Thank you for advice, my problem was due to something else (see edited question)

Comment: Atfer I created my correct reference, it was using the parent classes that had the desired effect, so I chose this as correct answer `.navbar .navbar-header img.jamClass { width: 50px; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
a.jamClass{width:50px !important;}
.jamClass{wdith:50px !important;}
```

use this !important to override the existing css file

**Note** - Removed `#.jamClass{width:50px !important;}` as this is not a valid selector you should only use .(period) for class # is for `id`

Comment: I tried all but it didn't work - I discovered by Site.css file was not created by default correctly... (see question)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the selection stronger like this

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-header img.jamclass {
  /* your code goes here */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <img class="jamClass" src="~/Content/Images/Gravit_Bridge_Sync.svg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `!important`, but I would read up on the problems with using !important.

Here is a good read - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

can you try one of the below CSS rules,

```css
img.jamClass{
  width:50px;
}
```

**or**

```css
.navbar-header img{
  width:50px;
}
```

Comment: I tried both but neither worked even though I know they should. My issue was due to the default-created MVC project (see question)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my issue was the Site.css file not being referenced at all.

In the **default** created MVC project, the BundleConfig had it as `site.css` (lower case) but it creates the file as `Site.css` upper case - it was as simple as that!!!!

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400087/site-css-is-not-working-for-my-sample-web-site) for where I found the suggestion.